# Read textbox and assign input to variable in another class

Tags: c#, class, textbox

I have tried going through similar questions and answers about this topic but I can't seem to find (or understand) a solution.

On Form 1 I have three text boxes that will receive user input. In a separate class I have a method that needs to access the input from those text boxes.

Form1.cs consists of just the text boxes and some buttons. The method in the other class is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace RealEstateApp
{
    public class RealEstateApp : Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());

            const double RENTAL_AMOUNT = 1000.00;

            RealEstateInvestment invest1 = new
                RealEstateInvestment(2004, 150000, "65th Street");
            invest1.MonthlyExpense = GetExpenses();
            invest1.IncomeFromRent = RENTAL_AMOUNT;
            invest1.DetermineMonthlyEarnings());
            RealEstateInvestment invest2 = new
                RealEstateInvestment("72 Westchester Dr.", 229000);

            invest2.MonthlyExpense = 900;
            invest2.IncomeFromRent = 1500.00;
        }

        public double GetExpenses()
        {
            double insurance;
            double taxes;
            double utilities;
            string inValue;

            inValue = txtBoxInsurance.Text; //Console.ReadLine(); (get user input from textbox)
            insurance = double.Parse(inValue);
            inValue = txtBoxTax.Text; //Console.ReadLine(); (get user input from textbox)
            taxes = double.Parse(inValue);
            inValue = txtBoxUtilities.Text; //Console.ReadLine(); (get user input from textbox)
            utilities = double.Parse(inValue);
            return (insurance / 12 + taxes / 12 + utilities);
        }

    }
}
```

As I am sure you experienced c# guys out there have already noticed, I am met with an error 'An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property.'

my static void Main() is in the second class if that changes anything.

*EDIT*

I have put the whole class code above now to give a better idea of what's going on.

Cheers,

Matt

Comment: remove static keyword...

Comment: If I do that then I get an error further up in my code when I call the GetExpenses() method.

Comment: this method in other class and textboxes in someother clasS?

Comment: looks like you are calling non-static property from static method.You need to create instance of Form1

Comment: @Matt one of the way would be to remove static keyword and move GetExpense() method in Form1.cs

Comment: Would I move all of this across to Form1 then?

`const double RENTAL_AMOUNT = 1000.00;

            RealEstateInvestment invest1 = new
                RealEstateInvestment(2004, 150000, "65th Street");
            invest1.MonthlyExpense = GetExpenses();
            invest1.IncomeFromRent = RENTAL_AMOUNT;`

Comment: @Rohit creating another Form1 is not the answer, adding parameters to the GetExpenses Method and removing the dependency to Form1 is IMHO the proper way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are getting error at 
`inValue = txtBoxInsurance.Text;`

This is because your `GetExpenses()` method is in static class .Whereas `txtboxInsurance` is private and non static property of class `Form1`. You cannot access non static method property from static method.

Instead What you can do is

```
public static  class YourStaticClass

static string _insurance;
static string _tax;
static string _utilities;

       public static double GetExpenses()
```

> ```
>     {
>         double insurance;
>         double taxes;
>         double utilities;
>         string inValue;
>
>         //Console.Write("Yearly Insurance: ");
>         inValue = _insurance; //Console.ReadLine(); (get user input from textbox)
>         insurance = double.Parse(inValue);
>         //Console.Write("Yearly Tax: ");
>         inValue = _tax; //Console.ReadLine(); (get user input from textbox)
>         taxes = double.Parse(inValue);
>         //Console.Write("Monthly Utilities: ");
>         inValue = _utilities; //Console.ReadLine(); (get user input from textbox)
>         utilities = double.Parse(inValue);
>         return (insurance / 12 + taxes / 12 + utilities);
>     }
> ```

And

```
public  partial class Form1 : Form 

 YourStaticClass._insurance=txtBoxInsurance.Text;
 YourStaticClass._tax=txtBoxTax.Text;
 YourStaticClass._utilities=txtBoxUtilities.Text;
```

I think this should work

Comment: That has helped get rid of the errors regarding GetExpenses as long as I dont put in `public static  class YourStaticClass` and `YourStaticClass._insurance=txtBoxInsurance.Text;
 YourStaticClass._tax=txtBoxTax.Text;
 YourStaticClass._utilities=txtBoxUtilities.Text;`

Comment: `YourStaticClass` is the name of the class in which you have created `GetExpenses()` method

Comment: Where abouts do I put `YourStaticClass._insurance=txtBoxInsurance.Text;
 YourStaticClass._tax=txtBoxTax.Text;
 YourStaticClass._utilities=txtBoxUtilities.Text;` ? I keep getting 'is a field but it used like a type' errors

Comment: under `Public Form1(){}`

Comment: I need to make _insurance etc public then.

Comment: I ran into subsequent errors in the program and have narrowed it down to the issue that the data isnt being correctly read from the textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the values of *textboxes* to function instead of *textboxes* it will decouple your class from the form class and you can use it by passing the values from any other class.

*Definition*

```
public static double GetExpenses(int pinsurance, int ptaxes, int putilities)
{
         return (insurance / 12 + taxes / 12 + utilities);
}
```

*Call*

Use [Int32.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to handle the exception for non int values in the textbox.

```
int insurance;
bool result = Int32.TryParse(txtBoxInsurance.Text, out insurance);
//Similarly you have to parse taxes and  utilities
GetExpenses(insurance, taxes, utilities);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Not quite sure I understand how to implement this change.